# Different p-values for Chi squared and Fisher's Exact R

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, fishers-exact-test

I'm trying to find whether there's a correlation between two variables using Chi Square test and Fisher's Exact test. I get two different p values when I run Chi Square test and Fisher's Exact test. Which value should I take? Take Chi squared p value and do not reject H0 or take Fisher's Exact p value ad reject H0?
I ran Fisher's Exact test as well because I get the following error msg when I run Chi Squared test.

Contingency table

[image]

```
> chisq.test(ebtable6)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  ebtable6
X-squared = 7.3866, df = 2, p-value = 0.02489

Warning message:
In chisq.test(ebtable6) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

> fisher.test(ebtable6)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  ebtable6
p-value = 0.05018
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not run two different tests. Choose your test first, before you run any tests and preferably before you examine your data values (though it would be permissible to consider the marginal totals).

By looking at both p-values before you decide which to use, you are (quite rightly) open to charges of p-hacking.

Since you're prepared to condition on the margins (you did an exact test after all), you could consider using simulated p-values to deal with the low expected in the (1,1) cell... I just did a million such simulations in R, it only takes a couple of seconds (the chisq.test default of 2000 is a bit small)

(However, you'll still have looked at the p-values... so that issue won't go away)

Comment: Hi, Glen! Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: chisq.test(matrix(c(4,5,23,20,104,496), nrow=3),simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 10000000)

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you for the code. The reason I used Fisher's Exact was because to do the Chi square test, 80% of the frequencies should be > 5. Since this is violated, I used Fisher's Exact on this. Is it wrong? I did the same with some other contingency tables and both Chi Square and Fisher's Exact gave the same answer.

Comment: That rule about expected frequencies has been known to be very conservative for a long time. See Bradley, D. R., Bradley, T. D., McGrath, S. G., & Cutcomb, S. D. (1979) Type I error rate of the chi square test of independence in r x c tables that have small expected frequencies. Psychological Bulletin, 86, 1200-1297.

Comment: @David Yes, thanks I'm aware. Indeed in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57228/quantifying-the-overlap-in-sort-task-results-with-cells-5/57294#57294) I said "*numerous studies since have argued that it's too conservative*". However, here the lowest expected gets down toward 1 and the simulation I suggested has a fairly different p-value than the ordinary chi-squared one does, so I decided it was not reasonable to say "it probably doesn't matter" when here it seems as if it actually may make a difference.

Comment: Is it possible to get two different values for p when simulated and not? For another contingency table, I get p = 0.007995 when not simulated and = 0.06747 with default B and p = 0.06633 with B= 10000000. Does this suggests there is no relationship between the variables?

Comment: @sug You get different values for p by simulating, yes, because the chi-squared statistic doesn't actually have a chi-square distribution (they're more likely to differ more when the warning is given). (If you didn't get different values by doing simulation what would be the point in doing it?). Again, you're making the error of computing multiple p-values for the same test and leaving yourself with the problem of choosing ... which leaves you again, in the territory of either (a) cheating or (b) looking like you are or (c) always having to take the *highest* p-value to avoid the accusation

Comment: So for anything that matters, pick a single statistic, and a single way of finding the p-value, and then work out what that p-value is

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you for the clarification :). I think I should take simulated p when the warning is given.

Comment: Generally the warning is given more often than necessary (as David points out above); If your smallest expected values are not substantially smaller than 5 it's usually fine to use the chi-square.

Comment: That makes sense and is conservative. If you are ambitious you could define a population with proportions as similar to your sample as possible but modified to make the null hypothesis true. Then sample from this population and compute Chi Squared for each sample and determine the proportion of  times the null hypothesis is incorrectly rejected at .05. Note that you wouldn't be fixing the marginal frequencies, just the proportions in the population. If the Type I error rate is not inflated a Chi Squared Test for your data is justified.

Answer (score 0):

This is not surprising since the tests have different statistical bases. The Fisher Exact test is a randomization test computed assuming both the row and column marginals are fixed (which they very rarely are) and is very conservative when they are not. The Chi Squared test is an approximation but works well in practice, even with sample sizes much smaller than yours. The warning message doesn't make sense since it is a given that an approximation is not exact so it's unclear what is meant by "incorrect." You have expected frequencies less than 5 that some might say is a problem, but simulation studies indicate it is not in most cases. In short, your marginals are not fixed so I recommend you go with the Chi Squared Test.

Comment: The warning does make sense, approximation with chi-square only make sense with more than sufficient sample size in each cell.

Comment: Warnings are based on expected frequencies not sample sizes. What doesn't make sense is to say that the approximation may be "incorrect" since it is a given that it is not exact and the meaning of "correct" in this context is hard to figure out. Perhaps it should have said "inaccurate." This  study shows that small expected frequencies are rarely a problem. Bradley, D. R., Bradley, T. D., McGrath, S. G., & Cutcomb, S. D. (1979) Type I error rate of the chi square test of independence in r x c tables that have small expected frequencies. Psychological Bulletin, 86, 1200-1297.